# How do I change the firefox bookmark icon?

Tags: firefox

How can I change firefox bookmarks icon? It keeps the standard whatever icon theme I choose

[image]

Edit: I want make firefox use the theme's icons(e.g. faience).

Comment: What did you try? What would you like to change it to? Kindly **Edit** the question to add this information

Comment: Aren't those Icons hardcoded into Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the star button by modifying the userChrome.css file as demoed in http://studioshorts.com/blog/2010/07/firefox-removing-the-star-bookmark-this-page-button/. However, if you look in to your Firefox profile in Ubuntu, you won't see any directory named 'chrome'.